# Is there a word/term for how pleasant a word is to pronounce?

Tags: single-word-requests, phonology, phonetics

I am familiar with **euphony** and **phonaesthetics**, but these both seem to focus more on how pleasant a sound is to hear/perceive. I think there is a subtle difference between this and how pleasant it actually is to **pronounce** a word, so I was wondering if there was a word for that specifically.

It's like *mouthfeel*, but for pronunciation.

Comment: I'd actually go with mouthfeel, as a singer enjoys *feeling the lyrics* written for a song.

Comment: We can say a phrase rolls off the tongue; mouthfeel (or mouth feel) reminds me too much of gluttonous articles about ice cream, or discussions by product designers working for chocolate bar manufacturers.

Comment: Most people don't think about the subject, let alone talk about it. And if they do, they tend to use long sonorous sentences instead of specialized words.

Comment: Oops, posted my answer "mellifluous” too hastily. Musical to *hear* not to speak.

Comment: Michael Harvey's "rolls off the tongue" is good, but "trips off the tongue" is a nice variant.

Comment: [**Dulciloquious**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/543502/365490): *sweet/pleasant to say*.

Answer (score 0):

'Silky smooth' and 'buttery'. "Teflony'?

This question had been asked in different forums in the past.

[AnswerBun](https://answerbun.com/) or [AnswerBun](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=What%27s%20the%20word%20for%20words%20that%20roll%20off%20the%20tongue%20answerbun.com&ia=web)

[Stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23529/whats-the-word-for-words-that-roll-off-the-tongue)

And a specific answer has not been found. There are some phrases that can be used to mean the same thing. I am providing some suggestions below as the original questioner in each forum was unsatisfied with the provided word choices.

**Super-phonatives** (Interestingly I could not find "*phonative"* in dictionaries, it is a commonly used term in medical sciences and it generally means the ability for phonation and/or the process of phonation)

**Super flowy words** (Flowy means which that flows, and flows easily)

**Words that glide** or **tongue gliders**

**Superfluid words**

> [From Brittanica](https://www.britannica.com/science/superfluidity)
>
> **superfluidity**, the frictionless flow and other exotic behaviour observed in liquid helium at temperatures near absolute zero (−273.15
> °C, or −459.67 °F), and (less widely used) similar frictionless
> behaviour of electrons in a superconducting solid. In each case the
> unusual behaviour arises from quantum mechanical effects.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually I wanted to write a comment. But that needs 50 rep.

Comment: Long lists of solutions are always best avoided. People might like 2 or 3 the best but disagree with all the others. For example, I have never heard the expression *Words that are slippery as an eel* and it also sounds horrible. You should edit and post 3 solutions at the most explaining why either one fits.